# Proof verification: $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, proof-verification

In this question, I will use $\sin^{-1}(x)$ instead of $\arcsin(x)$ since to me it's simpler this way.

Here's the proof that needs verifying:

$$y=\sin^{-1}(x)$$ hence, $$x=\sin(y)$$ $$\frac{dx}{dy}=cos(y)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{cos(y)}$$ then, using the $\sin^2(y)+\cos^2(y)=1$ identity, $\cos(y)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}$, or $\cos(y)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$, given that $x=\sin(y)$. However, since $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\sin^{-1}(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$, and $\cos(y) > 0$ in the given interval, it can be inferred that the answer is:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

the question is, is this proof correct, since at some point throughout this proof: it was implied that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec(y)$$ and therefore that $$\sec(y)=\frac{1}{\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

and I've proven numerically that this identity is true for the value $x=\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't know if this is true for every value of $-1 < x < 1$and if therefore, the means of proving I've used are false.

**TLDR:** Is this proof correct and rigorous?

Comment: Seems so.......

Comment: That fine, so you can conclude that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1} x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Fixed, thanks. @Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\cos(y)\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cos(y)}$$
is not formally rigorous.

The correct way to go about it is the following. By definition we have
$$x=\sin(\arcsin(x))\ .$$
differentiating both sides in $x$, we get
$$1=\cos(\arcsin(x))\arcsin'(x)\ .$$
Now we use, as you correctly did,
$$\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-\sin(\arcsin(x))^2} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
and conclude that
$$\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ .$$